# How do I debug a console app that seems to exit immediately on startup?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, logging, console-application

I have a console app that polls a POP3 server, and the very first thing it does is connect and log on. That takes maybe about one second normally. The application works find on my dev machine, but when I deploy it to the staging box, when I try and run it, all I see is a millisecond flash of a console window, and it exits.

I have added an `UnhandledException` handler to the `Program` class of the app that will hopefully tell me more (I can only tell when it's redeployed, a smallish process), but is there any source of error info outside of the app itself, like somewhere in Windows tracing or the error log. The Windows logs on the staging machine are huge, and I don't quite know what to look for or where to look.

Comment: Have you tried running it through command prompt? Do you see any errors there?

Comment: What do you mean by the `UnhandledException` handler? How is that implemented? And as Searock mentions.. running it within the command will allow you to see the exception thrown (if any), as the window won't immediately close out

Comment: Both VS and WinDbg allow to start process after attaching debugger... Usually installing WinDbg on non-dev boxes is more acceptable than VS.

Comment: Could you just put a `Console.ReadLine()` call in the `catch` statement?

Comment: Unhandled exceptions should appear in the Windows event viewer also

Comment: @Rob I'm talking about handling the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event. See the docs at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx